# Select image iphone simulator using phonegap camera api

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, camera

I'm new to Xcode and iPhone apps. I want to select an image from iPhone (camera or library) and send to PHP via ajax.

I'm using the phonegap framework, Xcode iPhone SDK version 3.1.x. On clicking button it calls function with parameter 0 or 1, but it does not initialize camera or display the library.

I used the code in [this link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/iPhone:-Camera-API).

it shows this error in debug console:

> 2010-03-25 23:36:02.337 PhoneGap[7433:207] Camera.getPicture: Camera not available.

The simulator doesn't have a camera, but photos (from library) also not working!

What might be the error?
I think when using `navigator.camera.getPicture` first check for camera and if not break and shows error ~?

Answer (score 1):

For using photo library in iphone simulator. You have to conforms to the delegate UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and alloc pickerview and set delegate on it and then check

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerView animated:YES];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how are you using that framework. But   UIImagePickerController   is the class I use to choose photos from the iPhone library or the device's camera. And all you need to do is set it to display the library:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//set your delegate and other properties...
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

or

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

You should check it out.
Cheers